# how to remove controller name and action name from cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp I need to change url for SEO. Ineed to remove controller name and use only action name my code is like this :

In view file

```
echo $this->Html->link('Our Partner',array('controller'=>'Homes','action'=>'partners'),array('escape'=>FALSE));
```

and in routes:

```
Router::connect(
    '/partners',
    array('controller' => 'homes', 'action' => 'partners')

);
```

But it is getting controller and action name by default how to remove that?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you used Home and home :) 
Otherwise your code is right.

Answer (score 0):

```
Router::connect(
    '/:query',    array('controller' => 'Homes', 'action' => 'partners',1)
    array('query' => '[a-zA-Z]+') );
```

Here id is numeric with regex. please see [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements)